# Bash array key indexing: Keys containing "/" and " "

Tags: string, bash, dictionary, indexing

I'm indexing a bash/zsh array with various keys. They keys contain spaces and forward slashes.

I am having problem assigning and accessing a value to the array. I've tried numerous iterations of adding "", {}, and $, but I can't get it to work.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
$ asdf=()
$ key="my/key key1"
$ asdf["$key"]="this works"
$ echo asdf["$key"]
```

And the expected output:

```
this works
```

This line appears to work for setting it. But I can't access the value using the key...

```
$ asdf=()
$ asdf[$"$key"]="my value"
$ echo $asdf
my value
```

Which is great! But I still can't access it using the key...

Here are some things I've tried for accessing the array:

1. $ echo asdf["${key}"]
   no matches found: asdf[my/key key1]
2. $ echo asdf[$"${key}"]
   no matches found: asdf[$my/key key1]
3. $ echo asdf[$""${key}""]
   no matches found: asdf[$"my/key key1"]
4. $ echo asdf[""${key}""]
   no matches found: asdf["my/key key1"]
5. $ echo asdf[""${key}""]
   no matches found: asdf[my/key key1]

Here are some alternative methods I've tried for setting the array:

1. $ asdf["${key}"]="my value"
   bad math expression: operand expected at `"my/key ke...'
2. $ asdf[${key}]="my value"
   bad math expression: operand expected at `"my/key ke...'
3. $ asdf[$key]="my value"
   bad math expression: operator expected at `key1'
4. $ asdf["$key"]="my value"
   bad math expression: operand expected at `"my/key ke...'
5. $ asdf["${key}"]="my value"
   bad math expression: operand expected at `"my/key ke...'

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If you really are using Bash, `$"$key"` means the localized version of `"$key"` (so if `"$key"` is "winter", it would be "vinter" if your locale is sv_SE, or "talvi" if your locale is fi_FI, or "зима" if your locale is ru_RU, provided of course that you have localization support for these strings in the first place).

Comment: Are you looking for `${asdf["$key]}`? Notice that for an array to be able to use strings as indices, it must be an associative array, defined with `declare -A asdf`.

Comment: Also, if you are really using Bash, the syntax for accessing the value of the key `"$key"` in the associative array `array` would be `${array[$key]}`. But confusinly the text of your question also mentions Zsh.

Comment: Your attempt that seems to be working creates a standard array, where strings in the index are converted to 0, and `echo $asdf` then implicitly does `echo ${asdf[0]}` and shows the first element.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be what you're trying to do in bash at least (I've no idea about zsh):

```
$ declare -A asdf
$ key='my/key key1'
$ asdf["$key"]='this works'
$ echo "${asdf[$key]}"
this works
```